# Query in constructing multipart form data using Fitnesse restFixture

Tags: rest, multipartform-data, fitnesse

I am trying to do a PUT request using Fitnesse REST Fixture.
But when I run this test case, it is throwing a null pointer exception. Kindly share your thoughts if any issues in this test case

```
|setHeader            |!-Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary0r7Su8bjJuE4gOOo-!|

|setMultipartFileName |!-Windows path to the File xyz.wav-!|

|setBody                                                                                                  |!-------WebKitFormBoundary0r7Su8bjJuE4gOOo
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="abc

1
------WebKitFormBoundary0r7Su8bjJuE4gOOo
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="def

1
------WebKitFormBoundary0r7Su8bjJuE4gOOo
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="xyz.wav"
Content-Type: audio/wav


------WebKitFormBoundary0r7Su8bjJuE4gOOo---!|

|PUT|REST API Location|200||
```